# Can't get basic XHTML to display correct in Safari

Tags: html, xhtml, safari

I'm learning HTML, and have composed the following test file in textedit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TD/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Safari's html capabilities</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Los Angeles Clippers</h1>
<p>The Clippers, owned by frugal Donald Sterling, 
   are always one piece away from being a piece away from 
   slipping into the playoffs.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I save this file as text1 with an html extension, but when I open this in Safari, it shows up as the code itself, not as it would display in a webpage.  I also have a DOCTYPE declaration, but I can't get that to show on here without screwing with the code.

'view source' shows that there's some extra things going on up top, but I can't paste what they are precisely because it's difficult to paste html code here without it being translated into the code itself.  It shows another DOCTYPE declaration, and then all the code from my file falls into the 'body' section of the html.

Help!

Comment: What Operating System do you work on?

Comment: Are you using some kind of IDE for this? Have you tried just pasting what's here into a plain ol' text editor, saving it and viewing that?

Comment: What happens without any doctype?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably saving the file in rich text not plain text. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1761665?threadID=1761665.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  For those who read this in the future, the solution is to press Control-Shift-T while in textedit to switch from richtext to plaintext.  You then save the document with a .html ending (instead of choosing for it to be .html from the extension dropdown menu).

Comment: @Marver - You are welcome, don't forget to upvote useful answers and accept the best answer (click on the "tick").

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're using an editor like Word, which adds more information to a file.

Try using Notepad++ (or regular Notepad) for Windows or TextWrangler in Mac.